# How to convert stacked columns with duplicate indices into multiple unique columns with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a cryptocurrency time-series data-set which has all of the different currencies vertically stacked. It has 3 columns for the date, currency and price. There date ranges are also different for each currency.

i.e.

```
>>> df
        Currency  Date    Price
0       0x        2017-08-16  0.111725
1       0x        2017-08-17  0.211486
2       0x        2017-08-18  0.283789
3       0x        2017-08-19  0.511434
4       0x        2017-08-20  0.429522
...     ...       ...         ...
657311  zurcoin   2018-02-04  0.003254
657312  zurcoin   2018-02-05  0.002774
657313  zurcoin   2018-02-06  0.001986
657314  zurcoin   2018-02-09  0.002684
657315  zurcoin   2018-02-10  0.002325
```

I need to instead have a column for each currency's price and the date as the index with only unique dates. There will be plenty of null values which I intend to replace with 0's.

i.e

```
date          0x_price  10mtoken_price  1337coin_price  ...
2017-08-16    1         4               (NaN)->0        ...
2017-08-17    2         5               (NaN)->0        ...
2017-08-18    3         6               7               ...
...           ...       ...             ...             ...
```

I've tried to iterate over the dataframe with a groupby as shown:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2["date"] = df["Date"].unique()
df2.set_index("date", inplace=True)

for currency, group in df.groupby("Currency"):
df2.loc[df2.index.isin(group.Date), f"{currency}_price"] = group["Price"]
```

This returned the desired column names and shape but the dataframe was filled with NaN's.

i.e.

```
date          0x_price  10mtoken_price  1337coin_price  ...
2017-08-16    NaN       NaN             NaN             ...
2017-08-17    NaN       NaN             NaN             ...
2017-08-18    NaN       NaN             NaN             ...
...           ...       ...             ...             ...
```

I also tried to achieve the same thing with df.join() as shown:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2["date"] = df["Date"].unique()
df2.set_index("date", inplace=True)

for currency, group in df.groupby("Currency"):
df2 = df2.join(group.set_index("Date")[["Price"]].rename(columns={"Price": f"{currency}_price"}))
```

This didn't get to finish executing before freezing up my computer. Perhaps it's inefficient and I'm working with around 650,000 entries?

I haven't been able to find the same type of problem here and I haven't been able to figure out a solution after checking the documentation. I've probably missed something but hopefully I've described the problem sufficiently. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that each date each currency has only 1 price, you can do this:

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Currency'])['Price'].mean().unstack().fillna(0)
```

the mean() function calculates average price, if multiple prices are in df for that ccy at that date.

Comment: Incredibly simple and worked exactly as required. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pandas `pivot_table` could help here. I would use:

```
resul = df.pivot_table(index=['Date'], columns=['Currency'], values=['Price']).fillna(0)
```

With your example data, it gives:

```
               Price          
Currency          0x   zurcoin
Date                          
2017-08-16  0.111725  0.000000
2017-08-17  0.211486  0.000000
2017-08-18  0.283789  0.000000
2017-08-19  0.511434  0.000000
2017-08-20  0.429522  0.000000
2018-02-04  0.000000  0.003254
2018-02-05  0.000000  0.002774
2018-02-06  0.000000  0.001986
2018-02-09  0.000000  0.002684
2018-02-10  0.000000  0.002325
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I wish I could choose multiple answers! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this'll work for your data size:

```
for coin in set(df['Currency'].values):
    new_column_name = 'Price_'+coin
    df.assign(new_column_name = lambda x: x['Price']*(x['Currency']==coin))
df.fillna(0).drop('Currency',axis=1).set_index('Date')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this solution and perhaps I implemented it incorrectly however I received `TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable` on the `df.assin()` line. I was able to achieve the desired result with the one-liners above but thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo: the idea is not to call the Series `x['Price']`, but to multiply it by the following expression (it's interpreted as 1 for `True` and 0 for `False`).

Comment: That aside, the other answers are clearer and more optimized. Never do a loop where you can use a `pandas` builtin!